# How do I remove the rest of this lever-style door handle?

Tags: doors, doorknob, removal

I'm trying to remove an old lever-style door handle (with no visible screws) that had a missing latch so was already non-functional. Following online tutorials on how to remove door handles and doorknobs with no visible screws, I made a bunch of progress (even got the plate off, revealing two screws beneath, which I also removed) but cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to remove the rest of the remaining structure.

Photos from different angles (both inside and outside) available here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BELUn.jpg

I suspect there's some kind of mechanism that I need to press/engage which will allow me to pull these remaining cylinders and the remaining inner-plate (?) out.

Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there is a threaded collar screwing through from one side to the other. I think if you use a small screwdriver / punch to undo it (as arrowed), this will release the two halves:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick — thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you removed long screws (in those recess holes I see in the pictures), then those held the two flanges together.  All that's holding them is the paint. try gently prying them off the painted surface & they should slide apart just fine.

If that wasn't the case, since you're trashing the remaining hardware anyway, pry up those retaining clips & remove the thin plates they're holding.  See what you can get at then.

Comment: Removing the thin plate (on the inside of the door) revealed this oily, internal spring mechanism but no additional screws: https://imgur.com/a/lNXNx5Y

I thought removing the screws would also cause the whole structure to come loose but it barely seemed to make a difference. Attempting to pry them off (assuming stuck to paint) didn't really work — they're stuck on good, suggesting there's something else holding them together. Really puzzling!